# iPhone UITableView within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datasource

I want to create an layout in that I want to put `UITableView`(SubTableView) inside `UITableViewCell` of the first `UITableView`(MainTableView). The problem which I am facing is that when I call the Data Source method of MainTableView, then all the `DataSource` Method are initialised but when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is executed then my SubTableView in not calling its `DataSource` Method for particular row of the MainTableView.

Instead it calls the `DataSource` Method of MainTableView and then it calls the `DataSource` Method for the SubTableView. My concern is that I want to call `DataSource` Method for SubTableView when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is executed for the MainTableView for particular row.

[image]

Comment: You need to check the tableView argument passed into tableView:cellForRow...: and then use needed dataSource.

Comment: I have created MainTableView in XIB and have created SUBTableView in tableView:cellForRow... through code. But what it dose it that it will first call the DataSource Method of MainTableView for visible rows and then it will call the DataSource Method for SUBTableView. For eg : If there are 2 visible rows of MainTableView and 5 visibleRows of SubTableView then it will call the DataSource Method for MainTableView first for 2 rows and then it will call the DataSource Method for remaining rows for SubTableView. So how to encounter that thing?